# Quick way of identifying superfluous library() in R script?

Tags: r

Is there a quick and easy way (e.g. a function call) to identify superfluous calls to `library()` in a script?

#### Best approach so far (manual approach)

First manually inspect the script with an eye for duplicate or unnecessary calls to `library()`. In cases where I'm not sure, I restart the R session, **do not** load the package in question, and see if everything runs as it should. Depending on how long the script takes to run, this can be a little slow and laborious.

Is there a faster/more robust way of identifying superfluous calls to `library()`?

#### Example

Here is a very minimal example

```
# script1.R
library(dplyr)
2 + 2
```

In this script, `dplyr` is not necessary, so some function run on `script1.R` should return `dplyr`, to indicate that it doesn't need to be loaded.

```
# script2.R
library(rvest)
library(rvest)
read_html("www.google.com")
```

In `script2.R` the second `library(rvest)` is superfluous so `rvest` should be returned (even though it's used within the script)

These examples are trivial, but actual use cases are long EDAs/scripts of 2000+ lines of code

Comment: I think it will be harder to find *redundant* calls to `library` versus finding *missing* calls. For instance, if it is really just one or two files, then I'd comment out any reference to `library` (perhaps just `sed -i -e 's/library/#library/g' *.R`) and then check for missing packages.

Comment: This is a job for the IDE. Eclipse for Java does it for Java classes.

Comment: `R CMD check` and `devtools::check` will check *packages* for such things, and report when it thinks you have failed to import requisite packages (in the package's `NAMESPACE` file). I don't know how to adapt that mechanism to look a solitary files. Perhaps you can at least temporarily place all of the files within a package structure, `check` the "package", and parse through the output.

Comment: Though a hack, in a github issue comment for the `future` package, the author shows that `future(...)` will know what libraries are used by the code (https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/206#issuecomment-372790040). From this, two options: (1) use `plan(sequential)` and `f <- future(...); f$packages` to find the list of packages; or (2) look in the source of `future` and see how they do it there so that you can do it without that package.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `packrat::clean()` for this purpose (docs https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/); this combined with lintr should solve your problem